# HTML+CSS Footer - formatting text beneath menu

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

Trying to get the text beneath the "Menu" (as in Picture 2) . What is the 'correct' way to do this? I have been playing around with the meniubot and textbox margins, padding, display:block, display:inline-block, float:left, clear:both but I can't get it properly aligned as seen in the second picture.

Any ideas? Maybe I should be using a different class for each text box and set custom margins?

What I have:

[image]

What it has to look like:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
        <div class="main">

            <div class="logo2">
                <a href="#"><img src="logo2small.png"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="meniubot">
                <a href="#1">naujienos</a>
                <a href="#2">krepšinio vadovas</a>
                <a href="#3">treniruotė</a>
                <a href="#">įdomybės</a>
                <a href="#">galerija</a>
                <a href="#">apie mus</a>
            </div>

            <div class="ytfb2">
                <a href="#"><img src="yttopedit.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="ftopedit.png"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="textbox">
                Wondering <br> how we can he <br> Ip your game <br> Basketball HQ <br> Lomprehensive <br> Resource <br> Designed for basketball

            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                Wondering <br> how we can he <br> Ip your game <br> Basketball HQ <br> Lomprehensive <br> Resource <br> 
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                Wondering <br> how we can he <br> Ip your game <br> Basketball HQ <br> Lomprehensive <br> Resource <br> Desiasketball coach
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                Wondering <br> how we can he <br> Ip your game <br> Basketball HQ 
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#footer{
        bottom:0px;
        background-image:url(meniuBG.jpg);
        height:252px;
        margin-top:220px;
    }

    .logo2{
        float:left;
        margin-top:35px;

    }

    .ytfb2{

        clear:both;


    }

    .ytfb2 a{
        float:left;
        margin-top:40px;
        margin-right:20px;
    }

    .meniubot{
        float:left;
        margin-left:15px;
        margin-top:40px;

    }

    .meniubot a{
        text-align: center;

        float:left;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style:italic;
        color:rgb(193,193,193);
        padding:0px 35px 0px 35px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }

    .textbox {
        float:left;
        margin-left:50px;
        margin-top:-20px;
        color:rgb(193,193,193);
        font-size:14;

    }
```

Comment: You should use list instead of <br> that will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list might help you.

```
<ul class="meniubot">
  <li>
    <a href="#1">Link</a>
    <div>text...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECd6J/

Comment: After formatting everything, setting the margins etc. I realised.. the Menu items are stuck to the text, how can I make a space between them? Like in the second picture

Comment: Nevermind - margin-top on the textbox. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: yep. *margin-bottom* and *display: block;* on the <a> would also work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to go into deepest coding practice.
Use `position:relative; display: block;` to whatever contents you want to play with.
It won't affect any other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the text box like the following:

```
 <html>
   <div class="container">
      <p>Wondering </p>
      <ul class="textbox">
            <li>How we can he</li>
            <li>Ip your game</li>
            <li>Basketball HQ</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

And change the CSS like the following:

```
.container{
   width:200px;
 }

.container p{
   margin-left:40px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.textbox li{
   list-style-type:none;
}
```